# Creating a getter method without interfering with Rails interworkings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, getter

I have a model with a text attribute `response`. this attribute contains a stringified version of a long json

I would like to do something like

```
def response
 JSON.parse(response)
end
```

so everytime I need it I would just call response

this, however, is a problem, since the response getter is used in Rails in other places.

I could name the method `parsed_response` or something similar, but I feel that it is not natural

is there a way to have a private getter?

Comment: Why is `parsed_response` not natural?  You're returning the result of `JSON.parse(response)` so it seems perfectly natural to me!

Comment: yes, so far thats what I am doing, but its always nice to learn something new

Answer (score 2):

There is a built-in way of automatically serializing/deserializing attributes in Rails. (I'm assuming you're using ActiveRecord). You can specify the columns to be serialized like so:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :response, JSON
end
```

You won't have an issue then with overriding the default getter method for the `response` attribute, and it will still be deserialized automatically in your own code.